# Jmeter - Hive giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/security/SaslRpcServer

Tags: hadoop, hive, jmeter

I am using Jmeter to create load on Hive.

While running the Jmeter I am getting the follwing error in the file `jmeter.log` :

```
 2021-02-05 10:11:02,927 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[HiveThreadGroupTWANG 1-1,5,main]
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/security/SaslRpcServer
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.security.HadoopThriftAuthBridge23.<clinit>(HadoopThriftAuthBridge23.java:66) ~[hive-exec-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.security.HadoopThriftAuthBridge.getBridge(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:82) ~[hive-exec-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.KerberosSaslHelper.getKerberosTransport(KerberosSaslHelper.java:55) ~[hive-service-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createBinaryTransport(HiveConnection.java:601) ~[hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:341) ~[hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:228) ~[hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107) ~[hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:103) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:652) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:534) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:734) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]

at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:362) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:198) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:635) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_281]
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    ... 21 more
```

The extra jars that I have added in the lib/ext directory are:
`old-hive-exec-3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar` 
`hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.5.0-152.jar.bkp`
`slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar`
`slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar`
`old-hive-service-3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar`
`old-hive-metastore-3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar`
`old-hive-jdbc-handler-3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar`
`old-hive-jdbc-3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152-standalone.jar.bkp`
`old-hive-jdbc-3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar`
`log4j-1.2.17.jar`
`libthrift-0.9.3-1.jar`
`libfb303-0.9.3.jar`
`hive-service-3.1.2.jar`
`hive-metastore-3.1.2.jar`
`hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar`
`hive-exec-3.1.2.jar`
`curator-client-5.1.0.jar`
`curator-framework-5.1.0.jar`
`zookeeper-3.6.2.jar`
`zookeeper-3.3.3.jar`
`hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar.bkp`

After moving `hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.5.0-152.jar` to the lib directory I am getting the follwoing error.

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration2/Configuration
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:43) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.5.0-152.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<clinit>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:41) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.5.0-152.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.create(UserGroupInformation.java:143) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.5.0-152.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:276) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.5.0-152.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.security.HadoopThriftAuthBridge.createClientWithConf(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:95) ~[hive-exec-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.KerberosSaslHelper.getKerberosTransport(KerberosSaslHelper.java:55) ~[hive-service-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createBinaryTransport(HiveConnection.java:601) ~[hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:341) ~[hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:228) ~[hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107) ~[hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:103) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:652) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]

      at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:534) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:734) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:362) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:198) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:635) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_281]
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration2.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to add `hadoop-common` .jar file to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Dependency libraries should go for **lib** folder, not to lib/ext folder, lib/ext is for [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)
3. You have `hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.1.5.0-152.jar.bkp`, I don't know what is .bkp file but I believe it should have .jar extension, most probably you downloaded something else
4. Are you aware of [jmeter-hadoop](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-hadoop) plugin? It looks like it can be useful for your use case, at least you will get dependency jars managed. See [How to Load Test HBase with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-hbase-with-jmeter) article for more details

Comment: I have edited the question with the new error I got after adding hadoop-common jar to the lib directory

Comment: Again the same problem, missing dependency jar in the classpath, I'm not going to re-visit the question each time you edit it